# Parse Xamarin Push broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, xamarin, push-notification

I'm using Xamarin with Parse for push notifications and I've got a problem what I can't solve. The iOS part is working, but I can't handle with the android one. I'm started with the project sample what I found in the Parse website. I changed all variables what needed and I get every data from device to the Parse database. When I looked the log of the device I see this :

> 12-18 08:37:16.363: W/GCM-DMM(446): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.clubs.uptheclub (has extras) }

The Parse say it's sent to the device , but the device don't show any activity ( just a bit wifi activity).

Here's some code:

AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.clubs.uptheclub">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.clubs.uptheclub.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.clubs.uptheclub.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application android:name="parsexamarinpushsample.ParseApplication" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="UpTheClub">
        <receiver android:name="parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.clubs.uptheclub" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="parse.ParsePushService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I Hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you force quit the application. If you are running on debug will suggest if you stop or close the app
while on debug. Reopen it again without debugging and then close it to see if you get the expected result, that way is not force quit.

I have done push notifications with parse on Android before but using Parse REST Api. Here a sample if helps:

[Parse Push Notification Sample](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/Xamarin.Samples/tree/master/Xamarin.Android)